# Recursively reverse a linked list in C

Tags: c, recursion, reverse, singly-linked-list, function-definition

Given the struct ListNode:

```
typedef struct _listnode
{
    int item;
    struct _listnode *next;
} ListNode;
```

how to recursively reverse a linked list using a function with void return type and single parameter for passing in the address pointing the head ListNode of the linked list? (note that the function should not have a return type; the reversed linked list is accessible from the outside of the function so that the elements can be printed)

```
void reverseList(ListNode **headptr)
{
    if ((*headptr) == NULL)
        return;

    ListNode *first = *headptr;
    ListNode *rest = first->next;

    if (rest == NULL)
    {
        *headptr = first;
        return;
    }

    reverseList(&rest);

    rest->next = first;
    first->next = NULL;
}
```

Apparently the code above only returns the first element of the original list, without being reversed, while the remaining elements are gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your function implementation is that in this call

```
reverseList(&rest);
```

the function changes the local variable `rest`

```
ListNode *rest = first->next;
```

instead of changing the data member `first->next`.

So in this if statement

```
if (rest == NULL)
{
    *headptr = first;
    return;
}
```

the local variable declared in the previous recursive call of the function is changed. You need to pass to each recursive call of the function the pointer to the original head node through pointer to it.

And you function has too many return statements.

The function can look the following way:

```
void reverseList( ListNode **head )
{
    if (*head && ( *head )->next)
    {
        ListNode *last = *head;

        *head = ( *head )->next;

        reverseList( head );

        last->next->next = last;
        last->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: tho I still cannot get the part: ```last→next→next = last;```

Comment: @Centauri_42 I removed the change of your function because it was not the one change that is required. The shown function contains all required changes.:)

Comment: hmm just asking what the ```last->next->next = last;``` line does in the function

Comment: @Centauri_42 If you look one more at your own code that contains these lines  ListNode *rest = first->next; and  rest->next = first; then you will understand that the last line in fact is the same as  first->next->next = first; Instead of the name first I use the name last in the function definition.:)

Answer (score 0):

The issues:

- The recursive call will make `rest` point to the node that originally was the tail of the list, so `rest->next = first;` is not right. `rest` is no longer pointing to what originally was the second node. Still, you have a reference to it with `first->next`, so you can use that and write:

  ```
  first->next->next = first;
  ```
- You must assign to `(*headptr)` so it points to the node that was originally the tail. After the recursive call, you know what that node is: `rest` points to it, so end your function with:

  ```
  *headptr = rest;
  ```

NB: Not a problem, but your second `if` block does not need to do `*headptr = first;`, as these two pointers are already equal.